# How to integrate GWT or Vaadin with Play Framework 2.0

Tags: gwt, playframework-2.0, vaadin

**Is is possible to implement the client side of a Play Framework 2.x web application using GWT or Vaadin?**

Play 1.x has a special module that provides GWT integration, but I can not find examples of the use of these technologies together in Play 2.x version. Can these technologies be integrated? Is there a module, or must some other approach be used?

Comment: Why is this question closed? I too would like to know the answer to how gwt and play2 can be used together. Has anyone used them to any degree? Outcomes, pros, cons? Thanks

Comment: It would be better if you attach the Play Framework 2 links you are using. I almost got it confused with PlayN framework!!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

GWT and Play2 can work together seamlessly, just as GWT can be used with python and go backends.

Using GWT with Play2 has two parts, *serving static files* and *client-server communication*.

- For the GWT produced static files (js, css, img..) you can just add them to the Play2 `public` directory, and they will be accessible based on the routes configuration.
- For client-server communication your best bet is using a pure json-rest approach, as request-factory, gwt-rpc have some dependency on J2EE servlets.

There are plenty examples of providing a json/REST api with Play2, and plenty examples of interacting with json/REST APIs with GWT.

Comment: Has anyone done this? I'm wondering how much serialization or parsing work there is to do with the json/REST api?

Comment: Is your backend Scala or Java?

Comment: I'm considering a Java backend under the Play framework,  and GWT frontend. I'm wondering how much the work might be like just to do the REST serialization and parsing, since Play does not use GWT RPC. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Henri Kerola demoed this recently for play 2.x and will give a talk at javaone this year: 
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IwuqAh0VSek

Comment: Great video! I can add the link: https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Scala+and+Vaadin+HOWTO

Answer (score 1):

I found a project on github which integrates Vaadin with Play 2.2:
https://github.com/henrikerola/play-vaadin-integration

Answer (score -2):

You can't use Vaadin with play2. Vaadin is basically a Java EE servlet that must live in a Java EE container such as Tomcat.

Play is not based on Java EE, it uses its own server.
As for GWT all server side code needs a Java EE container. But if you just want the client side then it's totally possible as it is with any web framework.
Just create json web services and remove server dependancies.
For an example in php : http://gwtquickstart.blogspot.fr/2009/11/call-php-script-from-gwt.html

Comment: this stuff is simply not true. there have been plugins for running gwt with play for 1.x and there are some for 2.x as well. the only thing gwt/vaadin needs from the servlet architecture is a way to communicate with the client.

Comment: then please provide us with an example