# Integrate GWT with Play2

Tags: gwt, playframework, playframework-2.0

Does anybody has experience of integrating Play2 with Google Web Toolkit? Is there any example projects which demonstrate how this can be done?

Comment: see http://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.0/gwt
and
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12909826/how-to-integrate-gwt-or-vaadin-with-play-framework-2-0

Comment: The first link is about play 1.0. The second doesn't answer the question. I am interested in knowing how to change build files to support gwt not in whether this is possible, I am sure it is possible.