# How to integrate GWT with Play framework 2?

Tags: gwt, playframework-2.0

`Play framework 1` has a module to integrate `GWT`. However, there is no such a module for `Play framework 2`.

I googled and found a similar question: [How to integrate GWT or Vaadin with Play Framework 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12909826/how-to-integrate-gwt-or-vaadin-with-play-framework-2-0) but I still don't know how to do it.

Is there any tutorial or any document? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

GWT can integrate with any server side language . important point is method of server side communication . GWT support two method : Request builder and RCP .
request builder at final convert to simple ajax  request . 

i think simplest way to integrate GWT with server side code is use of RESTFull service and server side (Actions of MVC should return data in json format) and request builder in client side.

in the fact , you don't need any special config . only try to find some Module or method for create REST services . (in my experience i integrated Zend(PHP) with GWT with this method without any problem)

Comment: Thanks for your response. Is it a good idea to integrate [Vaadin](https://vaadin.com/gwt) which already integrates the `GWT`?