# What backend features does Play Framework make easier than a pure GWT backend?

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, gwt, playframework, backend

I am condsidering implementing a webApp using GWT for the frontend, and Play framework for the backend (according to [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12909826/how-to-integrate-gwt-or-vaadin-with-play-framework-2-0)).  I am considering that since the Play framework has a good reputation for simplicity (akin to Ruby on Rails to which the Play Framwork attributes its inspiration), and with GWT I can have my frontend coded in Java [compiling to JS] also.

*I'd like to know what I can expect in the Play Framework backend to be simpler/easier compared to a pure GWT backend?  What things does the Play Framework backend make simpler/easier that would take more time/complexity with a GWT backend?*  My interest includes the specific objective features or steps that the Play Framework takes care of for you, that a GWT backend would have to explicitly implement instead; so this is not just a subjective *languageX vs languageY* question.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Assuming that by "GWT backend" you mean GWT-RPC (or RequestFactory), I'd be tempted to answer "nothing", with more code needed on the client-side to handle ser/deserialization of requests/responses.

Comment: Yes, GWT RPC would be what I was referring to.